# How to displaying product category before product title?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying to display the product sub-category name above the product title on the Shop or Product Archive page.

I've tried the code below but I am not sure how to get sub-categories instead of the category:

```
function category_single_product(){

$product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

    $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

    <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200687/only-show-sub-categories-for-a-post

Answer (score 1):

you can use get_term_children() function

```
$list_sub_cats = get_term_children($single_cat->term_id,'ca');
```

I hope this will help you, Visit to get more info https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/

Answer (score -1):

You can use `woocommerce_single_product_summary` and set priority. Try the below code. Code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function show_sub_category_before_title(){

    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
                     
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
     
        $product_cat = array();
     
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if( $term->parent != 0 ) {
                $product_cat[] = $term->name;
            }
        }
                             
        $product_cat = join( ", ", $product_cat );
        echo $product_cat;
    }
    
}    
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_sub_category_before_title', 1, 1 );
```

**Tested and Works**

[image]